# Attempt to read property "blog_category_id" on null

Tags: laravel-10

I am working with a blog module in laravel, I have created a table for categories and it is inserting data to a table, and blog_categories table has data, I am able to get all the categoties in a form where i need to create a post, but when I try to insert data i get an error "Attempt to read property "blog_category_id" on null" here is my code. Please help
Model

```
class Blog extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];

     public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(BlogCategory::class,'blog_category_id','id');
     }
}
```

Controller

```
 public function storeBlog(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'blog_category_id' =>'required',
        'photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
        'title'=>'required',
        'details'=>'required',
    ]);

    $ext = $request->file('photo')->extension();
            $final_name = time().'.'.$ext;
            $request->file('photo')->move(public_path('uploads/'),$final_name);
    $obj = new Blog();
    $obj->$request->blog_category_id;
    $obj->title =$request->title;
    $obj->details = $request->details;
    $obj->photo = $final_name;
    $obj->visibility = 0;
    $obj->created_by= null;
    
    $obj->save();
    dd($obj);
    return redirect()->back()->with('message','Blog Post created successfully');
}
```

Form

```
 <h3>Select Post Category</h3>
                <div class="mt-5">
                    <div class="custom-select">
                        <select name="blog_category_id" class="form-control">
                            <option selected="">Select Post Category</option>
                            @foreach($categories as $item)
                            <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->blog_category}}</option>
                              @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <div class="custom-select-icon la la-caret-down"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a mistake in your controller `$obj->$request->blog_category_id;` as you written, but the correct format is

```
$obj->blog_category_id = $request->blog_category_id;
```

actually you not given the database table's column name for `blog category_id`